# Nested LinearLayout stretch

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Consider this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/red"
                android:background="@color/Red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Red" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `TextView` is stretched horizontally all the way to the edges of the screen, but the height is limited by the string "Red" and is positioned at the top of the screen. Why is that so? Why is the `TextView` stretched in only one dimension?

When I switch the orientation of the `LinearLayout`s the effect is reversed: The `TextView` is stretched from top to bottom, but its width is limited by the string "Red" and is aligned to the left of the screen.

Comment: whenever you use weight property in linearLayout make sure to give layout_width = 0dp.

Comment: remove this android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the Android `weight` distribution is supposed to work. If a `view` has weight in a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal orientation`, then it will acquire importance/weight in horizontal direction only. Similar is the case with `LinearLayout` with`vertical orientation`, the view gains importance/weight in the vertical direction. That's how the android `weight` distribution works.

Note: Use `width`(in case of horizontal orientation) or `height`(in case of vertical orientation) as **`0dp`** instead of **'wrap_content'** for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` from `TextView` and check.

**Note:** If you are using `ConstraintLayout` then no need to take `LinearLayout`. Everything can be manage by `ConstraintLayout`. You just have to set proper constraints of Views.

Comment: Removing the layout_weight from the TextView makes it not stretch at all, it just sits in the top left corner. But the question remains: Why does it stretch in only one dimension?

Comment: Bz it takes mentioned orientation of LinearLayout. Suppose you have mentioned orientation Vertical, TextView height is wrap_content and weight=1 so it will stretch Top to Bottom. In this case width will remain wrap_content. If you have mentioned orientation Horizontal then TextView width is wrap_content and weight=1 so it will stretch Left to Right and height will remain wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

**Do Like This**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/red"
            android:background="@color/Red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:text="Red" />
```